Como leer archivo JSON
Estoy tratando de leer un archivo JSON; pero simplemente el método me dice que no se puede encontrar el archivo.
El archivo JSON lo tengo dentro de la misma carpeta:

Y al intentar leerlo con esta línea:
Object jsonO = new JSONObject(new FileReader("Menu.json"));

Me dice que no en encuentra el archivo, y con esta línea:
Object jsonO = new JSONObject("Menu.json");

Me dice que... ...más bien, le entiendo que el  archivo JSON debería empezar con { . Yo entiendo que el formato del archivo JSON está erróneo, pero el archivo JSON ya lo pase por un formateador y no me marca ningún error de formato.
Esta es la estructura del archivo JSON que tengo:
{
  "m1": "Dashboard",
  "m2": "Email",
  "smEmail": [
    {
      "sm1": "Inbox",
      "sm2": "Read",
      "sm3": "Compost"
    }
  ],
  "m3": "Chat",
  "m4": "Calendar",
  "m5": "UI Kit",
  "smUI Kit": [
    {
      "sm1": "Accordion",
      "sm2": "Alerts",
      "sm3": "Badges",
      "sm4": "Breadcrumbs",
      "sm5": "Buttons",
      "sm6": "Button group",
      "smButton group": [
        {
          "ssm1": "Button 1",
          "ssm2": "Button 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Como tienes tus imports?

Lo he intentado con json.simple y con org.json

Que mensaje de error te arroja, o simplemente no muestra nada?

Con la libraria de JSON.org me arroja este error: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] y con el otro solo que no encuentra el archivo

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que podrías intentar:
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/Main/Menu.json"); // Ruta de tu JSON
            JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader)); //Convertir a objeto JSON
            System.out.println(jsonO.toString(4)); //Imprimir contenido
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

La ruta puede variar, en mi caso el paquete de mi proyecto es Main dentro de el está el JSON por lo que la ruta quedaría:

src/Main/Menu.json


En esta línea:
Object jsonO = new JSONObject(new FileReader("Menu.json"));

en lugar de utilizar "Menu.json" debes utilizar lo siguiente:
"src/com/practica/Menu/Menu.json"
Siempre que utilices archivos trata de poner la ruta completa del archivo, tanto si vas a leer como si vas a escribir

Por si no se entendió, cada que intentes cargar un archivo que no sea una clase de java, le tienes que especificar la ruta completa del archivo que quieres cargar independientemente del tipo de archivo. Por ejemplo, aquí estabas intentando cargar un archivo JSON qué ño tienes en tu proyecto de java, peor oara cargarlo tienes que especificar en donde está dicho archivo, pero solo a partir de la carpeta raíz o fuente de tu proyecto osea, de la carpeta src en adelante
